# arm cortex log10 function sometimes returns 0

Tags: c, arm, math.h

I'm using stm32f4xx mcu with `<math.h>` lib

when I convert the mW to dBm, used `log10f()` function

but, the `log10` function return value is not valid occasionally.

here is my code:

```
volatile float power = 0.0f;
volatile float data  = 0.0f;
volatile int power_conversion = 0;

power = Interpolation();       // this function returns mW value
data = 10 * log10f(power);     // <-- wrong value returns, [dBm Conversion]
```

also I have recognized some conditions of wrong value:

expected value is -53.xx dBm when the value -4.7x10<sup>-6</sup> but returns zero

the power value -4.7x10<sup>-5</sup> does not occur in error (-43.xx dBm)

but, the value exceed 10<sup>-6</sup> does occur in error (returns 0)

10<sup>-5</sup> -> OK

10<sup>-6</sup> -> Wrong return 0

does anyone know this?

---

#resolved
#my stupid brain fault

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for log10f [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log10)? Specifically if the argument is negative then the result is NaN. And thinking about it logically you shouldn't have a negative power value. Try `data = 10 * log10f(abs(power));` and look into why `Interpolation()` has a negative return value.

Comment: thank you for your answer i will check the related documents and look into the logic

Comment: ah.. my interpolation logic always returns the minus power value because of calibration. the cal data is related in the rf power which is radiated in minus power value now i've solved that issue (my code bug...)  really thank you for the answer again

Comment: Also note that you will get an invalid result if `power == 0`.

Comment: @chqrlie 0 Watts = -inf Dbm